# Problem in C# Xml deserialization

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

In my project, legacy code generates xml which has following structure :

```
<Output>
    <Template recordID=12>
        <Employer type="String">
            <Value>Google</Value>
            <Value>GigaSoft inc.</Value>
        </Employer>
        <Designation  type="String">
            <Value>Google</Value>
        </Designation>
        <Duration  type="String" />
    </Template>
</Output>
```

I want to deserialize this xml into object which has following properties (**I am using C#**):

```
public class EmployerInfo
{
    string[] _employerName;
    string[] _designation;
    string _duration;
}
```

I tried to deserialize above xml using following attributes around members (NOTE : I have simplified code. I know we should not make data members public. This code is just for experimental purpose)

```
[XmlElement("Template")]
public class EmployerInfo
{
    [XmlElement("Employer")]
    public string[] _employerName;

    [XmlElement("Designation")]
    public string[] _designation;

    [XmlElement("Duration")]
    public string _duration;
}
```

To deserialize, in main class I wrote :

```
XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Output));
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\sample_xml.xml");
EmployerInfo fooBar = (EmployerInfo)serial.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```

After executing above code, all the members in fooBar object are set to null (default values). I think this is because xml structure does not match with class structure.

I tried to automatically generate class using xsd command but it created seperate classes for each of the data member .

I tried to give element names like XmlElement("Employer.Value") , XmlElement("Template.Employer.Value") but this also didnt work.

Can anyone please suggest some way to fit this xml into a `EmployerInfo` class ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
[XmlType("Template")]
public class EmployerInfo
{
    [XmlArray("Employer"), XmlArrayItem("Value")]
    public string[] _employerName;

    [XmlArray("Designation"), XmlArrayItem("Value")]
    public string[] _designation;

    [XmlElement("Duration")]
    public string _duration;
}
public class Output
{
    public EmployerInfo Template { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Output));
        using (var reader = new StringReader(@"<Output>
    <Template recordID=""12"">
        <Employer type=""String"">
            <Value>Google</Value>
            <Value>GigaSoft inc.</Value>
        </Employer>
        <Designation  type=""String"">
            <Value>Google</Value>
        </Designation>
        <Duration  type=""String"" />
    </Template>
</Output>"))
        {
            EmployerInfo fooBar = ((Output)serial.Deserialize(reader)).Template;
        }
    }
}
```

Note also tat the type returned from `XmlSerializer(typeof(Output))`'s deserialize method is going to be a `Output` record.

Comment: do we need to specify XmlRoot() attribute above public class EmployerInfo line?